# printing PayPal response

Tags: api, paypal

I am writing this code to get response

```
$PayPalResult = $PayPal->GetTransactionDetails($PayPalRequestData);
echo '<pre />';
print_r($PayPalResult);
```

After using **print_r** command I am getting following result.

```
Array
(
[RECEIVERBUSINESS] => rdaa.org
[RECEIVEREMAIL] => rdudeja.org
[RECEIVERID] => RS2THGDSKDKG6
[EMAIL] => bEGIN@denim.com
[PAYERID] => RPXDF4PDMRQD6
[PAYERSTATUS] => verified
[COUNTRYCODE] => US
[SHIPTONAME] => Kamal  Sudeja
[PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
[PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
[L_NAME0] => denim
[L_NUMBER0] => 1234
[L_QTY0] => 1
[L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
[L_CURRENCYCODE0] => USD
[L_TAXABLE0] => false
[ERRORS] => Array
    (
    )

[ORDERITEMS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [L_NAME] => denim
                [L_DESC] => 
                [L_NUMBER] => 1234
                [L_QTY] => 1
                [L_AMT] => 
                [L_TAXAMT] => 0.00
                [L_EBAYITEMTXNID] => 
                [L_EBAYITEMORDERID] => 
            )

    )
```

I am writing the following code to get it  print as associative array.

```
foreach($PayPalResult as $k=>$v)
{
   echo $k.'='.$v.'<br>';
}
```

But it is showing Error

> "Array to String Conversion"

Help me I want print that response.

Comment: um `ORDERITEMS` and `ERRORS` are arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through $PayPalResult.  The params it includes are already parsed and available for you, so you can just use $PayPalResult['EMAIL'] to pull that value, for example.

The only things you might want to loop through would be $PayPalResult['ORDERITEMS'] or $PayPalResult['ERRORS'] which are arrays themselves, as @Daniel A. White mentioned in his comment.

In that case, though, it would be something like this...

```
foreach($PayPalResult['ORDERITEMS'] as $OrderItem)
{
    $ItemName = $OrderItem['L_NAME'];   
}
```